# Derby SQL Error: Please explain

Tags: database, derby

I'm having a eclipse RCP application which using Derby as its database at my hands.
When checking through the log files I found the following error output over and over again in:

```
SQL State:  40XL1
Error Code: -1

XID       |TYPE         |MODE|LOCKCOUNT|LOCKNAME                                                                        |STATE|TABLETYPE / LOCKOBJ                   |INDEXNAME / CONTAINER_ID / (MODE for LATCH only)  |TABLENAME / CONGLOM_ID                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** The following row is the victim ***
7838655   |ROW          |X   |0        |(2,35)                                                                          |WAIT |T                                     |NULL                                              |PROFILES                              |
*** The above row is the victim ***
1504395   |ROW          |X   |3        |(2,36)                                                                          |GRANT|T                                     |NULL                                              |PROFILES                              |
7740323   |ROW          |X   |3        |(2,38)                                                                          |GRANT|T                                     |NULL                                              |PROFILES                              |
1179235   |TABLE        |IX  |2        |Tablelock                                                                       |GRANT|T                                     |NULL                                              |PROFILES                              |
1252538   |TABLE        |IX  |14764    |Tablelock                                                                       |GRANT|T                                     |NULL                                              |PROFILES                              |
1504395   |TABLE        |IX  |2        |Tablelock                                                                       |GRANT|T                                     |NULL                                              |PROFILES                              |
1537719   |TABLE        |IX  |2        |Tablelock                                                                       |GRANT|T                                     |NULL                                              |PROFILES
```

I don't know much about Derby so I'm pretty lost at that error. So far I found out that it has something to do with not being able to get a lock on a table. I assume it's the `Profiles table` since it's the only mentioned table.

The `Profiles table` consists of only two lines which store timestamps that are updated regularly.
Could someone explain to me in detail what exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: The error message belonging to that SQL State is: "*A lock could not be obtained within the time requested*": http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefexcept71493.html  The "within the time requested" is probably the key. You need to check the application